# How to format tick lines in tableau to be between date or how to change date format to discrete without changing the look of graph

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau for a timeline line chart. Basically, I want the date e.g. 1991, 1992, 1993, to appear between the tick lines. So the tick shouldn't be above and in the middle of 1991 but on the left and the right side like '1991' if " ' " where the tick line of x-axis.

When I change the date format to discrete the format is as I want it, but the graph changes and looks differently.

How can I get this result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you post a sample someone might be able to suggest changes to help you.

Comment: Once the look changes, try adjusting the settings in the Marks card to 'line' to being your chart back to the line graph?

Answer (score 0):

Changing a pill from *continuous* to *discreet* can change the automatic marks on your chart. If you have a line graph, change the pill to *discreet* and see your chart change to a bar chart, you can revert back to a line chart by changing the settings on the *marks* card as illustrated below.

[image: Look at the marks card]

[image: Then select your desired chart type]